# JavaFX Non-Blocking Dialog to process result when Ok clicked

Tags: java, javafx

A discussion more than a question. The answer could be simply Yes, unless there is other approaches possible or are better.

What is usually the approach for a non blocking dialog that needs to do some work after clicking OK?

A blocking dialog can return the result.

```
Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
```

I was thinking in order to change my dialog design from blocking to non-blocking, I could implement an ActionEvent within my Dialog that does the work and set it to the OK button onAction.

Is that the best approach? I don't think there is any other approach, considering that onClosingEvent has no way of knowing which button was clicked (OK or Cancel).

```
getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(ButtonType.OK, ButtonType.CANCEL);
final Button okButton = (Button) getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
okButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        //Do the work that normally would be done outside of the Dialog on returned Optional<ButtonType>
    }
});
```

Perhaps it would be better to get the Ok button from the dialog where you have instantiated it, and add the ActionEvent there. That way you can use both showAndWait() and show(). If the ActionEvent was within the Dialog, then the showAndWait returned result would be redundant no longer necessary or any usable.

```
MyDialog dialog = new Dialog();
Button okButton = dialog.getOkButton();
okButton.setOnAction();
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html

> JavaFX dialogs are modal by default (you can change this via the initModality(javafx.stage.Modality) API). To specify whether you want blocking or non-blocking dialogs, developers simply choose to call showAndWait() or show() (respectively). By default most developers should choose to use showAndWait(), given the ease of coding in these situations. Shown below is three code snippets, showing three equally valid ways of showing a dialog:

**UPDATE 07/02/2019**

In working with JFoenix JFXDialog which is only non-blocking I have tried using CompletableFuture to await the result.

```
final CompletableFuture<String> resultFuture = createDialog();
final String result = resultFuture.get(); // This could be placed in a Task<Void> to keep it non-blocking.

public CompletableFuture<String> createDialog() {
    final CompletableFuture<String> messageFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

    okButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        messageFuture.complete(textField.getText());
        dialog.close();
    });

    return messageFuture;
}
```

The CompletableFuture is created where I create my JFXDialog, then returned. 
The OK and CANCEL buttons on the dialog is either calling the resultFuture.cancel or resultFuture.complete

Comment: Another option is to create a Runnable, place `dialog.showAndWait()` in that Runnable’s run method, and pass the Runnable to Platform.runLater.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to listen to the [`result`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#resultProperty) property.

> A property representing what has been returned from the dialog. A result is generated through the [result converter](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html#resultConverterProperty()), which is intended to convert from the [`ButtonType`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/ButtonType.html) that the user clicked on into a value of type R. Refer to the [`Dialog`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) class JavaDoc for more details.

If the result type of the `Dialog` is `ButtonType` (such as when using an `Alert`) then you'll know what button is pressed directly. Otherwise, the result converter is responsible for determining the result based on what button is pressed. That means you can combine a result converter with listening to the result to do the appropriate thing when the result is set.